# What cards can retrieve arbitrary cards from exile?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

By "arbitrary" I mean the card retrieved need not be related to the card doing the retrieving. Red's impulsive draw mechanic and flicker cards that exile and immediately retrieve another permanent don't count, but it's fine if the spell limits the category of cards that can be retrieved, like Karn.

Comment: Are you including all of the Eldrazi Processors?

Comment: Can *wishes* retrieve cards exiled by other effects in game? For example, Death Wish from Judgement says: "Choose a card you own from outside the game and put it into your hand...".  Modern example: "Wish" from AFR says "You may *play* a card you own from outside the game this turn." Or is the exile zone an "in-game" zone?

Comment: @BradC Exile is a regular game zone and thus not outside of the game. In casual play, outside of the game means any card outside of your starting deck, including your entire collection. In sanctioned play it means any card in your sideboard.

Comment: Thanks, @Hackworth. Found the reference for that, it's 400.1, which defines the seven game zones, one of which is "exile", and 400.11, which defines anything not in a game zone as "outside the game". So wishes can't (currently) retrieve cards exiled via (normal) game effects. Interestingly, I believe this was changed at some point, see 400.8: "Previously, the exile zone was called the "removed-from-the-game-zone"; this seems to match up to my memory that the old-school Wishes could to this when originally printed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not completely sure this covers everything, but as far as I know in most cases you can only interact with cards face-up in exile. So doing a scryfall search for the words [face-up + exile](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22face-up%22+o%3Aexile&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) reveals 6 cards:

- [Ashiok, Nightmare Muse](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashiok%2C%20Nightmare%20Muse) (only grabs from opponent though)
- [Coax from the Blind Eternities](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Coax%20from%20the%20Blind%20Eternities) (only grabs eldrazi)
- [Karn, the Great Creator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Karn%2C%20the%20Great%20Creator) (only grabs artfacts)
- [Mirror of Fate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirror%20of%20Fate) (quite risky, exiles your deck)
- [Pull from Eternity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pull%20from%20Eternity) (puts the card in the grave)
- [Riftsweeper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Riftsweeper) (shuffles the card in the deck)

There is also:

- [Kaya the Inexorable](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kaya%20the%20Inexorable) whose emblem lets you cast face-up legendary cards (and face down legendary cards that you can view) that you own from exile
- [Runic Repetition](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Runic%20Repetition) (only grabs cards with flashback)
- [Rootcoil Creeper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rootcoil%20Creeper) (only grabs cards with flashback)
- [Memory Theft](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Memory%20Theft) (only grabs opponents' Adventure cards)
- The [Eldrazi Processors](https://scryfall.com/search?q=type%3Aeldrazi+type%3Aprocessor&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name), and [Processor Assault](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Processor%20Assault) which can put cards your opponents have in exile in to their graveyards.

Comment: [Kaya the Inexorable](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=503834) can cast legendaries from exile and doesn't explicitly mention face-up, although its rulings touch on it. I'm not sure if there is anything else using this template, which is influenced by the fact that it also looks at your hand and graveyard.

Comment: @Cadence You can cast face-down legendaries with Kaya's emblem if you were allowed to look at them at any point after they were exiled face-down. Relevant rules are 601.3f in combination with 406.3.

Comment: Also: Runic Repetition, Rootcoil Creeper, Memory Theft, Processor Assault.